# MySQL inner join?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have 3 tables (2 columns)such as

```
table s   
NUM  GRADE
1    A    
2    B    
3    C   
5    D   

table p  
NUM  GRADE
1    B  
2    C  
2    D  
3    A  

table g  
NUM  GRADE
1    A  
3    C  
3    B  
4    D
```

I want to inner join them each other such (on s.NUM=p.NUM=g.NUM) as

```
NUM  GRADE   
1    A  
1    B  
1    A    
2    B  
2    C  
2    D  
3    A  
3    C  
3    B
```

What should I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine a `UNION ALL` query with a query which identifies common `NUM` values shared between all three tables.  In my query below below, this latter table serves a filter to remove any `NUM` records which do not appear in all three tables.

```
SELECT t1.NUM, t1.GRADE
FROM
(
    SELECT NUM, GRADE FROM s
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NUM, GRADE FROM p
    UNION ALL
    SELECT NUM, GRADE FROM g
) t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT s.NUM
    FROM s INNER JOIN p
        ON s.NUM = p.NUM
    INNER JOIN g
        ON s.NUM = G.NUM
) t2
    ON t1.NUM = t2.NUM
ORDER BY t1.NUM
```

Comment: what if there is a record in table s that doesn't exist in table p and g? It is included in the result

Comment: Yeah, I get it...give me 30 seconds